# Good books on fields and Galois theory

Tags: reference-request

What are some good books on field and Galois theory?

Comment: Good for whom?  Please clarify what target audience you have in mind:   someone who has never seen the topics before, someone looking for a further study after a first course, or a general reference? 

Comment: Voting to close- this is too general for a reference request.

Comment: I strongly agree with KConrad and Daniel Moskovich. A reference request shouldn't simply be *"What are references for X?"* Without any extra information, you may as well just look at what is well-reviewed on amazon: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=field+galois+theory&x=-177&y=7

Comment: I do not agree that Amazon gives scholarly information on books. On the contrary, they even do not give the standard library information like the publication year. When writing references for nlab I find amazon ads useless in providing full information including publisher, existing editions, original reference if it is a translation and so on. 

Comment: My favorite book on Galois theory is Patrick Morandi's FIELD AND GALOIS THEORY. It's not only the most complete book I've seen on the subject,it's the most readable. Definitely worth having. 

Answer (score 1):

David Cox "Galois Theory" Wiley 2004 is my current favorite. Lots of interesting material and very nicely written.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 1.5 The Absolute Galois Group of a Finite Field
Might be useful from [Field Arithmetic](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2445111) by Fried and Jarden.

Answer (score 0):

[Galois Theory](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/notre-dame-mathematical-lectures/Galois-Theory/toc/ndml/1175197041) by Emil Artin is a nice treatment of the latter.